# How does a done signal from a context help in cancelling a request?

Tags: go, channel

This is a code snippet from the golang context page https://blog.golang.org/context

```
func httpDo(ctx context.Context, req *http.Request, f func(*http.Response, error) error) error {
    // Run the HTTP request in a goroutine and pass the response to f.
    c := make(chan error, 1)
    req = req.WithContext(ctx)
    go func() { c <- f(http.DefaultClient.Do(req)) }()
    select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            <-c // Wait for f to return.
            return ctx.Err()
        case err := <-c:
            return err
    }
}
```

The description for this method says

> The httpDo function runs the HTTP request and processes its response in a new goroutine. It cancels the request if ctx.Done is closed before the goroutine exits:

How is the request cancelled here? the way i see it, even if the context is done, we are still waiting for the result from the request? how does this help?

Comment: The request gets a new context in `req = req.WithContext(ctx)` and cancels _itself_ if thix context is canceld in which case it will return early.

Comment: Re context: cancelation is a request to stop - and not a "kill" command. Its up to the blocking function to honor the cancelation - and in its own time. The standard library supports context cancelation in `net/http`, `database/sql` etc. - and you can be assured those implementations support fast cancelation. Canceling a write using, say a NFS filesystem package, may have a significantly longer clean-up time.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that context is passed to `http.DefaultClient.Do(req)` using `req = req.WithContext(ctx)`, so `req` argument keeps context inside. Function`http.DefaultClient.Do()` uses it and will exit as soon as original context (`ctx`) is cancelled.

In fact I wouldn't say that  "httpDo function cancels the request", it is cancelled through `ctx` by caller of `httpDo`. Using goroutine here is arguable, we can just return `f(http.DefaultClient.Do(req))`

Answer (score 0):

`Do(req)` will exit with an error as soon as context is cancelled. You're right that we're still waiting for a value in `c` but we should get it almost immediately after context cancellation. Also, it's not necessary to wait for completion of `Do(req)`. It's possible to just early return from the function based on your use case.

Of course, random `func Foo(ctx context.Context)` function will not necessary listen to a context so it is not safe to assume that all the functions that take the context will handle the cancellation correctly. You should act based on documentation and/or code.